# If the base space of a vector bundle is of finite type, then the total space is?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I'm reading Bott-Tu "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology", and have a question about Proposition 6.13 (p.60).

On the same page, it is mentioned that if $E$ and $M$ are orientable manifolds of finite type, then $H_c^{*}(E)\cong H_c^{*-n}(M)$. (Here, let $\pi:E\to M$ be a vector bundle.) Therefore, I think the hypothesis of proposition 6.13 should deduce that $E$ is of finite type. Then, my question is that "if $M$ is of finite type, then $E$ is ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a locally trivial fibre bundle over an $n$-manifold $M$. Suppose that $\mathcal{U}$ is a good open cover of $M$. According to Corollary 6.9 in Bott-Tu we have the following.

> The restriction of $E$ to each member of $\mathcal{U}$ and to each nonempty intersection of members of $\mathcal{U}$ is the trivial bundle.

Thus if $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$ is a finite subset with $U_{\mathcal{V}}=\bigcap\mathcal{V}\neq\emptyset$, then there is a diffeomorphism
$$E|_{U_\mathcal{V}}\cong U_\mathcal{V}\times F\cong \mathbb{R}^n\times F$$
where $F$ is the fibre of $\pi$ and we have made use of the fact that $\mathcal{U}$ is a good cover to get $U_\mathcal{V}\cong\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\pi$ is a vector bundle, then $F\cong\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, and we see that we already have a good cover of $E$ given by $\pi^{-1}\mathcal{U}=\{\pi^{-1}(U)=E|_U\mid U\in\mathcal{U}\}$. In particular $E$ has a good cover of the same cardinality as as any good cover of $M$.